# state not updating correctly with moment format in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, web-frontend

I am using datepicker in a reactjs project but when i format the date with moment, the state is not being updated with the actual value that is selected

`

```
 const [dates, setDates] = useState([])
```

```
const onDateChange = (values) =>{
  setDates(values.map(item=>{
    return  moment(item).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  }))

  console.log("dates:", dates);
}
```

```
<RangePicker
    onChange={onDateChange}
/>
```

Comment: whats it being updated with?

Comment: it picks the date of the system instead of the date that is selected from the dateRange

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the problem but logging the value right after setState won't print the new state.
If you want to see the updated state you can create a useEffect function with the dates in the dependency array.

You can read more about it here https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#troubleshooting

Comment: thank your very much for your answer. but the output i get on console is usually the date of today and not what i selected @simcha

Answer (score 0):

I think you should open anonymous function inside the `setDates` and type what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what is the exact implementation of your `<RangePicker .../>` component. However I would like to point 3 important things out here, hope it will help :)

1. As `<RangePicker .../>` component is an input type, you would get its value from event that is passed as an argument to your `onDateChange` callback.
2. You are consoling the state at an event handler callback. This event handler callback will be sent to the input component and you would get the state lagging by 1 step. The reason it happens is the callback is prepared during initialisation of the React App when the state is empty. When you click it logs that state taken by it during initialisation and then state is set and re-rendering happens.
3. The state should be used as the value for your `<RangePicker .../>` component in order to make UI consistent. Make sure moment's date format is same as range picker date type.

In conclusion, it is not the moment that is causing issues. Hope if you verify and fix the above 3 it should work.

Please refer the example with an date input element:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState();

  const onDateChange = (ev) => {
    //1. Use event.target for state updates
    setDate(ev.target.value);

    /*2.1 Below console log goes with the input component,
      This will take date what is currently set and not what we select.
      The selected date is in the input's event.target
    */
    console.log("date at input:", date);
  };

  //2.2 This one stays with the react component and updates when state updates
  console.log("date at App:", date);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        //3. The state should be used as value for your input component
        value={date}
        type="date"
        id="birthday"
        name="birthday"
        onChange={onDateChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please log the date in console inside a useEffect which gets fired upon change in the dates state like :

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("dates : ", dates);
},[dates])
```